# How to send two values of the same collections with async.each method?

Tags: javascript, async.js

I am trying to calculate the distance between n points using the google distance matrix api.

Here is the code

```
var sum=0;
for(i=1;i < locations.length;i++){
var origin = locations[i-1];
var destination = locations[i];
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status !== 'OK') {
        alert('Error was: ' + status);
      } else { 
        sum += response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
      }
  });        
 }
```

But this doesn't work.As my loop finishes way fast then the google distance matrix response. I know this is wrong and it won't work. Hence I decided to go with my favourite asynchronous library async.js. But then how do I do this?

```
origin = locations[i-1]  
destination = locations[i].
```

I just get a single element of the collection with async.each which was my method of choice. What method of async.js should I choose to deal with such issues? Or should I adopt some entirely different way to work around this problem?

Help is appreciated
Saras

**EDIT**
To those who are asking why am I doing this?. I want to calculate distance as accurately as Uber does for its own application and I am collecting a lot of data points(location coordinates real-time) for that. But I don't know how they can calculate the distance that accurately(another way is directions API but I find it not that great). I can only guess they are using the distance matrix API and applying it over 100 data points across a trip to calculate distance.

Comment: If you want to get a distance matrix, wouldn't you need to pass all locations to Google at once?

Comment: No I cannot do that. I need to calcuate the distance between say x to y. What I am trying to do to calculate distance from x to x1, x1 to x2, x2 to x3 and x3 to y.Adding all four will generate distance between x  and y. If I give all `n` coords in an array it will result in a `nxn` matrix. Which I don't want.

Comment: Hm, calling `service.getDistanceMatrix` looked like you *did* want to get the matrix. And actually, I still believe that is what you *should* do, as the n×n matrix does contain the values you are looking for (on the next-to-main diagonal). Making only one request is a) cheaper on the network b) faster c) doesn't require you to use async.js.

Comment: You should synchronously make an array of origin-destination tuples. Then use `async.map` or `async.mapSeries` on it. Don't use `async.each`.

Comment: @Bergi could you write an answer with the method as suggested showing your approach in code. It would be more clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the elements from the array synchronously and put them in another array:

```
var legs = [];
for (var i=1; i<locations.length; i++)
    legs.push({origin:locations[i-1], destination:locations[i]});
```

You then can use the async.js method of your choice to iterate that array, probably either `map` or `mapSeries`, or maybe `reduce` if all you want to do is to sum the distances.

```
async.map(legs, function(leg, cb) {
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [leg.origin],
        destinations: [leg.destination],
        …
    }, cb);
}, function(err, responses) {
    …
})
```